# Most efficient way to use selectors in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

is it more efficient to use `$('.active')` or `$('div.active')` ?  I have always avoided including "div" because it's extra text in the javascript file I don't want the user to have to download.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think OP means when all the possible elements that may have `active` are all `<div>` elements, should `div` be included in the selector.

Comment: @patrick - yes, that's what I mean, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Older versions of IE will benefit from the inclusion of `div` because they don't support `getElementsByClassName()`.

Because of that, *every* element on the page needs to be selected with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

...and manually tested to see if it has the `active` class.

If you include `div`, then it is able to narrow it down a bit, since it can do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

...then test only those elements.

When I say *older versions*, I mean IE6 and IE7 since IE8+ supports `querySelectorAll`.

---

**EDIT:**

Browser suppport:

- `getElementsByClassName`: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11
- `querySelectorAll`: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13

Comment: On the other hand, you reduce your efficiency by selecting with the tag name if you do it by id.  e.g. $('#my_id') is more efficient than $('div#my_id').  The reason is pretty much the same - except that even browsers as antiquated as IE6 have `getElementById()`.

Comment: @Kyle: Good point. The tag name shouldn't be included with an [`id-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you mean performance.
I prepared special test for everyone on [JSPerf: jquery class selector test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-selector-test).
On my browser and computer (FF 3.6.13 and Core 2 Duo 1.6) `div.active` is a bit slower. But found it variable - it seems GC has something doing here.

And after few more tests it seems that `div.active`:

- Speed is variable on FF, sometimes GC turns on 'div.active' test, but generally difference is very small.
- Unnoticable difference on Chrome and Safari
- Faster on IE9

Comment: When I ran the test a few times `div.active` was almost always a little faster, though each time the difference was negligible.

Comment: I used the same version of FF that you did. I also tested in Safari. (I tried in Chrome, but the javascript fails for some reason.) When the results are that close, you really need to run the test several times to get a more balanced result.

Answer (score 1):

I like to include the tag name if it helps self-document the code.  If I can use

```
$("nav.primary")
```

instead of

```
// this is the primary nav
$(".primary")
```

I tend to do it.

Comment: If the time difference is negligible, then I think this approach is very sound.  Naturally, if you were to change your code later on, you'd have to change it in two places, but that downside is worth the upside IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to get some speed on large pages is to use find instead.

$( your-container ).find("div.active")

Since you always? know where you should look, you can create your own scope. So that the browser only need to search within that area of code.

By the way, you don't need to care about size of the css, EVER :)
Use css minifing tools to minimize the css when the site is in production mode. You can also set your web server to automatically gzip your css files before sending the to the user. And if you don't change your css filename on every pageload, the browser cache up to whole css file.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors in jQuery used to be optimized similar to how you would do it for browsers, see: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Specifying a generic tag anywhere, even with an ID or class would be dramatically slower than just specifying the ID or class alone. See:

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/demos/how-to-optimize-jquery-selectors/

The above uses jQuery 1.3. Since jQuery 1.4 and the introduction of the Sizzling selector engine, this is less important from what I understand. See:

http://hungred.com/useful-information/jquery-optimization-tips-and-tricks/

For myself, I decided in CSS to use whatever reads the easiest, and I am more specific there since that is only parsed once. In jQuery, however, I have been more careful since those selectors could run thousands of times over the life of a page.